# Quiero imprimir los tres primeros valores de un numero

Tags: c#

Quiero imprimir los tres primeros números de un valor, por ejemplo: si es valor es 123456789 la imprimir se muestre "123". He estado probando con string.formart, pero no funciona.

```
 double digito = 123456780;
    
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:###}", digito));
```

Comment: Investiga sobre la funcion substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien puedas utilizar [Substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.substring), la recomendacion es [AsSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asspan).

Si bien cuando haces esto para "unas pocas cadenas" no tiene mucha sobrecarga en performance, pero cuando tienes que realizar esta tarea en muchas cadenas y y el tamaño de dchas cadenas tambien importa "puede afectar la performance", porque como sabras debemos cuidar al trabajar con string en C# [ya son inmutables](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0#Immutability) y por ejemplo [Substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) genera nuevas cadenas en cada accion por eso la recomendacion de [AsSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asspan) que devuelve un ReadOnlySpan

Ejemplo con ambos metodos
(lo puedes probar online aqui https://dotnetfiddle.net/x1IVnp )

```
    var number = 123456789;
    Console.WriteLine($"number={number}");
    
    //Obtener primeros 3 digitos de un numero
    
    //Utilizando Substring
    var digits3_v1 = number.ToString().Substring(0,3);
    Console.WriteLine($"digits3_v1={digits3_v1}");
    
    //Utilizando AsSpan
    var digits3_v2 = number.ToString().AsSpan(0, 3);
    Console.WriteLine($"digits3_v2={digits3_v2}");
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Aviso de rendimiento/mejora: CA1846: Preferencia de AsSpan sobre Substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1846)
- [String.Substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.substring)
- [MemoryExtensions.AsSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asspan)
- [Strings: Inmutabilidad y la clase StringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0#Immutability)

Comment: muchaaas gracias, enserio era lo que estaba buscando.